# Alternative Process

Tags: vb.net, variables, datagridview, textbox

I have 2 buttons and a DataGridView with 2 Columns (0 & 1).

- The 1st button transfers a randomized cell from the Column(1) to a TextBox. Then, it stores that Cell in variable (a), plus the cell that opposites it in variable (b).

  ```
  Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
      Dim rnd As New Random
      Dim x As Integer = rnd.Next(0, Form1.DataGridView1.Rows.Count)
      Dim y As Integer = 1
      Dim a As String = Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value
      Dim b As String = Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y - 1).Value
      TextBox3.Text = a
  End Sub
  ```
- The 2nd button, however, is supposed to compare if another TextBox's text has the same string variable (b) has as Strings. Now, if so, then it has to display a certain message and so on...

  ```
  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      If TextBox4.Text = b Then '<<< ISSUE HERE!
          MsgBox("Correct! ^_^")
      ElseIf TextBox4.Text = "" Then
          MsgBox("You have to enter something first! O_o")
      Else
          MsgBox("Wrong! >,<")
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

The problem is that the variable (b) is surely not shared across the two "private" subs. And so, there is NOTHING to compare to in the 2nd button's sub! I presume that the solution here is to split the "randomization process" into a separate function, then execute it directly when the 1st button gets activated. Furthermore, that function's variables have to be SHARED somehow, and I certainly don't know how!

---

Thanks for Mr. Olivier, the code has been improved significantly! Yet, I still encounter a "wrong" comparison issue, somehow!

`Dim RND As New Random
 Dim x As Integer`

```
Private Function GetCell(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal cellIndex As Integer) As String
    Return Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(cellIndex).Value
End Function

Private Sub btnRoll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoll.Click
    x = RND.Next(0, Form1.DataGridView1.Rows.Count)
    tbxRoll.Text = GetCell(x, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If tbxSubmit.Text = GetCell(x, 0) Then
        MsgBox("Correct! ^_^")
    ElseIf tbxSubmit.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("You have to enter something first! O_o")
    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong! >,<")
    End If
End Sub</code>
```

---

<s>Well, unbelievably, I read a guide about "comparison operations" in VB.net and tried out the first yet the most primal method to compare equality - which was to use .Equals() command - and worked like a charm! Thank God, everything works just fine now. ^_^</s>

`If tbxSubmit.Text.Equals(GetCell(x, 0)) Then`

Alright now... This is going to sound weird! But, following Mr. Olivier's advise to investigate "debug" the code, I rapped the string I'm trying to compare with brackets and realized that it's been outputted after a break-line space! So, I used the following function to remove the "white-space" from both of the comparison strings! And it bloody worked! This time for sure, though. ^_^

`Function RemoveWhitespace(fullString As String) As String
        Return New String(fullString.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray())
    End Function`

If RemoveWhitespace(tbxSubmit.Text) = RemoveWhitespace(GetCell(x, 0)) Then

Comment: If you need to remove leading and trailing spaces only, just use `myString.Trim()`.

Comment: Great! Yeah, that would do it. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the local variables into class fields.

```
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim a As String
Dim b As String

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    x = rnd.Next(0, Form1.DataGridView1.Rows.Count)
    y = 1
    a = Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value
    b = Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y - 1).Value
    TextBox3.Text = a
End Sub
```

These fields can now be accessed from every Sub, Function and Property.

Of course `Button3_Click` must be called before `Button2_Click` because the fields are initialized in the first method. If this is not the case then you should consider another approach.

Create a function for the Cell access

```
Private Function GetCell(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal cellIndex As Integer) _
                                                                          As String
    Return Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(cellIndex).Value
End Function
```

And then compare

```
If TextBox4.Text = GetCell(x, y - 1) Then 
    ...
```

And don't store the values in `a` and `b` anymore. If `y` is always `1` then use the numbers directly.

```
If TextBox4.Text = GetCell(x, 0) Then 
    ...
```

---

One more thing: give speaking names to your buttons in the properties grid **before** creating the `Click` event handlers (like e.g. `btnRandomize`). Then you will get speaking names for those routines as well (e.g. `btnRandomize_Click`).

---

See:
- [VB.NET Class Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/class-vbnet)
- [Visual Basic .NET/Classes: Fields](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET/Classes#Fields)

Comment: Debug your code. Set a breakpoint on the comparison line. Run the code and inspect the variable, execute the methods in the quick watch window etc. See: https://www.google.ch/search?q=visual+studio+C%23+debugging+introduction

Comment: Thank you kindly, Mr. Olivier. You are a true Master. ^_^